# What is the parse error referred to in this error?

Tags: agda

I made an emacs file `Prelude.agda` containing the information on this page: http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/ssft18/lec1/Prelude.agda. After loading with `C-c C-l` I receive the error:

```
/Users/M/Prelude.agda:19,11-11 /Users/M/Prelude.agda:19,11::19,11: Parse error (n : â„•) â†’ â„• -- To use ...
```

The error points to the following line:

`data â„• : Set where
  zero : â„•
     suc  : (n : â„•) â†’ â„•`

What is the parse error?

Comment: just align `zero` and `suc` with the same tabulation and it should parse ok I think

Comment: @MrO Thanks :), but that doesn't work. I get `/Users/M/Prelude.agda:19,20-20
/Users/M/Prelude.agda:19,20: Parse error
â†’<ERROR>
 â„•`

Comment: Yes, sorry, there is a bigger issue, which I explained in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an encoding problem on the web page whose content you copy pasted in your emacs file, which is why it does not typecheck.

For example, the entity `â†’` should be displayed `→` which is why Agda does not accept this specific definition because it thinks it should be some kind of operator defined earlier.

However, since the encoding problem is all over the file, replacing this specific instance of the problem would not solve it for the whole file.

Another example is `â„•` that should appear as `ℕ`.

---

I corrected the file for you:

```
-- 8th Summer School on Formal Techniques

-- Menlo College, Atherton, California, US
--
-- 21-25 May 2018
--
-- Lecture 1: Introduction to Agda
--
-- File 1: The Curry-Howard Isomorphism

{-# OPTIONS --allow-unsolved-metas #-}

module Prelude where

-- Natural numbers as our first example of
-- an inductive data type.

data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : (n : ℕ) → ℕ

-- To use decimal notation for numerals, like
-- 2 instead of (suc (suc zero)), connect it
-- to the built-in natural numbers.

{-# BUILTIN NATURAL ℕ #-}

-- Lists are a parameterized inductive data type.

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  []  : List A
  _∷_ : (x : A) (xs : List A) → List A   -- \ : :

infixr 6 _∷_

-- C-c C-l   load

-- Disjoint sum type.

data _⊎_ (S T : Set) : Set where  -- \uplus
  inl : S → S ⊎ T
  inr : T → S ⊎ T

infixr 4 _⊎_

-- The empty sum is the type with 0 alternatives,
-- which is the empty type.
-- By the Curry-Howard-Isomorphism,
-- which views a proposition as the set/type of its proofs,
-- it is also the absurd proposition.

data False : Set where

⊥-elim : False → {A : Set} → A
⊥-elim () {A}

-- C-c C-SPC give
-- C-c C-, show hypotheses and goal
-- C-c C-. show hypotheses and infers type

-- Tuple types

-- The generic record type with two fields
-- where the type of the second depends on the value of the first
-- is called Sigma-type (or dependent sum), in analogy to
--
--   ∑ ℕ A =  ∑   A(n) = A(0) + A(1) + ...
--           n ∈ ℕ

record ∑ (A : Set) (B : A → Set) : Set where  -- \GS  \Sigma
  constructor _,_
  field  fst : A
         snd : B fst
open ∑

-- module ∑ {A : Set} {B : A → Set} (p : ∑ A B) where
--   fst : A
--   fst = case p of (a , b) -> a
--   snd : B fst
--   snd = case p of (a , b) -> b

infixr 5 _,_

-- The non-dependent version is the ordinary Cartesian product.

_×_ : (S T : Set) → Set
S × T = ∑ S λ _ → T

infixr 5 _×_

-- The record type with no fields has exactly one inhabitant
-- namely the empty tuple record{}
-- By Curry-Howard, it corresponds to Truth, as
-- no evidence is needed to construct this proposition.

record True : Set where

test : True
test = _

-- C-c C-=  show constraints
-- C-c C-r  refine
-- C-c C-s  solve
-- C-c C-SPC give
-- C-c C-a   auto

-- Example: distributivity  A × (B ⊎ C) → (A × B) ⊎ (A × C)

dist : ∀ {A B C : Set} → A × (B ⊎ C) → (A × B) ⊎ (A × C)
dist (a , inl b) = inl (a , b)
dist (a , inr c) = inr (a , c)

dist' : ∀ {A B : Set} → A × (B ⊎ A) → (A × B) ⊎ (A × A)
dist' (a , inl b) = inl (a , b)
dist' (a , inr c) = inr (c , c)

-- Relations

-- Type-theoretically, the type of relations over (A×A) is
--
--   A × A → Prop
--
-- which is
--
--   A × A → Set
--
-- by the Curry-Howard-Isomorphism
-- and
--
--   A → A → Set
--
-- by currying.

Rel : (A : Set) → Set₁
Rel A = A → A → Set

-- Less-or-equal on natural numbers

_≤_ : Rel ℕ
zero  ≤ y     = True
suc x ≤ zero  = False
suc x ≤ suc y = x ≤ y

-- C-c C-l load
-- C-c C-c case split
-- C-c C-, show goal and assumptions
-- C-c C-. show goal and assumptions and current term
-- C-c C-SPC give
```

Comment: Thanks :). The file seems to be full of errors. How am I supposed to know how to correct them? Is there a way of converting the characters into the correct characters?

Comment: may I ask how you were able to make this conversion? I also have to do it for the other files on this website: http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/ssft18/

Comment: I did it manually. The notions in this file are very common and their names are also common so I was able to translate them. If my answer is conform to your expectations, please consider validating it. As for the other files in this lecture, I suggest you ask Andreas Abel (who is a very active agda expert) to send you the originals.

Comment: As a side note, you can also notice that, at some points in the files, there are comments that are meant to explain how to input a given unicode character, for instance the comment `-- \ : :` tells you how to input `∷` in the emacs mode which can help you if you intend to manually change the others files, while I still suggest it would be better to ask for the originals.

Comment: @user65526 The most likely reason you are getting these files in garbled form is because your web browser is assuming these files are in ISO/IEC 8859-1 or some similar encoding. We can get them to display correctly by telling the web browser that the text is actually utf-8. For example in Firefox you would do this via `View > Text Encoding > Unicode`.